# How to avoid temporary variables when creating new column via groupby.apply

Tags: pandas

I would like to create a new column `newcol` in a dataframe `df` as the result of

```
df.groupby('keycol').apply(somefunc)
```

The obvious:

```
df['newcol'] = df.groupby('keycol').apply(somefunc)
```

does not work: either `df['newcol']` ends up containing all `nan`'s (which is certainly not what the RHS evaluates to), OR some exception is raised (the details of the exception vary wildly depending on what `somefunc` returns).

I have tried many variations of the above, including stuff like

```
import pandas as pd
df['newcol'] = pd.Series(df.groupby('keycol').apply(somefunc), index=df.index)
```

They all fail.

The only thing that has worked requires defining an intermediate variable:

```
import pandas as pd

tmp = df.groupby('keycol').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(somefunc(x)))
tmp.index = df.index
df['rank'] = tmp
```

Is there a way to achieve this without having to create an intermediate variable?

(The documentation for [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) is almost content-free.)

Comment: What do your data actually look like?  Also, are you sure you want a groupby and apply together (i.e. not `agg` instead)?  When you say "they all fail", a specific error message would be helpful, as would a description of what exactly you are trying to do by doing this operation.

Answer (score 8):

Let's build up an example and I think I can illustrate why your first attempts are failing:

Example data:

```
n = 25
df = pd.DataFrame({'expenditure' : np.random.choice(['foo','bar'], n),
                   'groupid' : np.random.choice(['one','two'], n),
                  'coef' : randn(n)})
print df.head(10)
```

results in:

```
       coef expenditure groupid
0  0.874076         bar     one
1 -0.972586         foo     two
2 -0.003457         bar     one
3 -0.893106         bar     one
4 -0.387922         bar     two
5 -0.109405         bar     two
6  1.275657         foo     two
7 -0.318801         foo     two
8 -1.134889         bar     two
9  1.812964         foo     two
```

So if apply a simple function, `mean`, to the grouped data we get the following:

```
df2= df.groupby('groupid').apply(mean)
print df2
```

Which is:

```
             coef
groupid          
one     -0.215539
two      0.149459
```

So the dataframe above is indexed by `groupid` and has one column, `coef`.

What you tried to do first was, effectively, the following:

```
df['newcol'] = df2
```

That gives all NaNs for `newcol`. Honestly I have no idea why that doesn't throw an error. I'm not sure why it would produce anything at all. I *think* what you really want to do is merge `df2` back into `df`

To merge df and df2 we need to remove the index from df2, rename the new column, then merge:

```
df2= df.groupby('groupid').apply(mean)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.columns = ['groupid','newcol']

df.merge(df2)
```

which I *think* is what you were after.

This is such a common idiom that Pandas includes the `transform` method which wraps all this up into a much simpler syntax:

```
df['newcol'] = df.groupby('groupid').transform(mean)
print df.head()
```

results:

```
       coef expenditure groupid    newcol
0  1.705825         foo     one -0.025112
1 -0.608750         bar     one -0.025112
2 -1.215015         bar     one -0.025112
3 -0.831478         foo     two -0.073560
4  2.174040         bar     one -0.025112
```

Better documentation is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html).

Comment: This is a great answer that is the kind of thing that could even benefit the answerer in around, say, 8 years.

Comment: @JonSpring eight years from then, which is tonight, interestingly.

Comment: even after all these years I find idiomatic Pandas hard to do regularly and consistently.